# Getting error " Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

This is what is in the header file.

```
/// Creates a new file geodatabase in the specified location.
/// @param[in]    path The location where the geodatabase should be created.
/// @param[out]   geodatabase A reference to the newly-created geodatabase.
/// @return       A long integer indicating whether the method finished successfully.
EXT_FILEGDB_API long CreateGeodatabase(const std::wstring& path, Geodatabase& geodatabase);
```

This is what my dllimport looks like.

```
[DllImport("FileGDBAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "#49", SetLastError=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public static extern int CreateGeodatabase([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string path, ref IntPtr geodatabase);
```

..and this is the code thats using it.

```
IntPtr Geodatabase = IntPtr.Zero;
                FileGDBAPI_wrapper.CreateGeodatabase("c:\temp\testGDB.gdb", ref Geodatabase);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402280/trouble-with-c-c-dllimport-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory

Comment: Maybe this is somehow related - you need to put an at-sign before the "c:\temp\testGDB.gdb", so that the "\t"-s won't be tabs... Maybe the error you're getting is just a bug in the library.

Comment: @Filip - yeah I saw that one....didn't help

Comment: It would help if you posted the definition of the native function.

Comment: @Ed not sure what you mean by that but I don't have access to the c++ code, just header files.

Comment: Ok then, that was what I was asking for.

Comment: Ok I have some code to do the C++ string bridging but don't know how to get it to work. I created an C++/CLR project and it compiled but the function isn't available for some reason. Tried a couple ways to make it public but kept getting errors. http://www.nuclex.org/articles/5-cxx/10-marshaling-strings-in-cxx-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible problems:

1. The C++ code is using a wide string, the C# code an ANSI string
2. The C++ code is using the `std::wstring` class, and not a c style null terminated string

I don't think you can fix the second problem easily without changing the API on the C++ side

Comment: Yes, Pinvoke can't marshal to a std:wstring (or a std:string).  You'll either have to change the C++ function to take a WCHAR* or write some C++/CLR bridge logic.

Comment: What would the C++/CLR bridge logic look like? :-)

Comment: Ok I have some code to do the C++ string bridging but don't know how to get it to work. I created an C++/CLR project and it compiled but the function isn't available for some reason. Tried a couple ways to make it public but kept getting errors. http://www.nuclex.org/articles/5-cxx/10-marshaling-strings-in-cxx-cli

Comment: @Donny I've never used managed C++. You can use Swig to create a wrapper over your C++ code, or export the functions as plain c. I've mainly used plain c so far.

Comment: I know nothing about C or C++, I'm just shooting in the dark at this point.

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you are using .NET 4.0, try passing parameters without the `ref` keyword.</del>

<del>i.e.</del>

<del>FileGDBAPI_wrapper.CreateGeodatabase("c:\temp\testGDB.gdb", /*ref*/ Geodatabase);</del>

<del>and let me know if this works for you.</del>

**EDIT**

Forget about my previous answer, I was typically ignorant.

I think you need to mark the `Geodatabase` as `out` instead of `ref` in both the declaration and invocation of the function; in this case you will **NOT** need to initialize your IntPtr before passing it to `CreateGeodatabase()`

I guess -and may be I am still ignorant - the problem related to declaring the Geodatabase argument in your library as a reference not as a pointer, that is, you can't pass null (IntPtr.Zero) to it, and typically, you don't need so, you need it as an out parameter.

Comment: The C# argument is an IntPtr, which is a struct, so if it is not passed by reference it cannot be modified by the native function.  If it were a reference type you would be correct.  Unless there is something in .NET 4 that I am unaware of that really changes how this stuff works, I don't see how your answer would work.

Comment: Switching out the "ref" for the "out" actually caused an "unbalanced stack" error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is useful

```
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, wstring& os ) {
            using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
            const wchar_t* chars = 
                (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(s)).ToPointer();
            os = chars;
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
        }
```